Whats the name of this 2000's action movie set in the U.K.?
I was with my friend while he was getting a tattoo in 2011, there was a movie playing in the background that I was able to watch some of and I've never found an info on the title. I only caught bits and pieces of the movie.
I remember It was set in the U.K., as you could tell by the main character(s) stealing a British cabbie in order to get where they needed to go. I believe it involved a loan shark/drug lord who threatened the main character or his family. The distinct part I remember is the main character finding someone he is looking for in the english countryside, where a rave is about to take place, the man the main character is meeting is making money from the rave and selling cocaine/ecstasy or some narcotic. I don't remember much other details but the main character seemed like a bad-ass on a mission.
Not animated, believe it's 2000-2010 but not sure, I know it was on DVD. possibly involved a big named star or rapper if i remember right, or just one of the guys maybe looked like one. Any help would be appreciated! 

Was the protagonist black?

sniff sniff I smell an answer forthcoming. :)

Not really. :) Just a couple of vague possibilities. I don't remember a cab-jacking in either.

Possibly a Guy Ritchie Film?

I found it! It is Dead Man Running:

A loan shark gives ex-con Nick a period of 24 hours in order to pay back the money he owes. Up against it, Nick involves his best mate on a multi-part mission in order to raise the cash before it's too late for them both.

After looking up The 51st State it was under like titles. Thanks guys!

Don't forget to accept this answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.
